# W/DocumentsContract: Failed to create document | Error when creating a saving a file on Android/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to save/export a file on the user Documents shared folder so it can be persistent if the application is deleted (it's an export of the user work on the application). Following [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory) to create a save a file on the shared folder, I have this basic implementation:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        registerActivity =  registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                result.data?.data?.let { writeInFile(it, "this is a test") }
            }
        }
    }

     private fun createFile() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply{
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "filename.txt")
            putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE)

        //this.registerActivity.launch(intent)
    }
    

    private fun writeInFile(uri: Uri, text: String) {
        val outputStream: OutputStream
        try {
            Log.i("export", uri.toString())
            outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)!!
            val bw = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(outputStream))
            bw.write(text)
            bw.flush()
            bw.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

The **createFile** function is called from a click event to export the data.

The Activity for choosing the folder to save is launching, but saving is failing. I am getting the following error:

```
    2021-06-23 18:24:43.268 2853-2871/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parent document isn't a directory
        at com.android.internal.content.FileSystemProvider.createDocument(FileSystemProvider.java:244)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider.createDocument(DownloadStorageProvider.java:207)
        at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.callUnchecked(DocumentsProvider.java:1124)
        at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.call(DocumentsProvider.java:1067)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.call(ContentProvider.java:2448)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:517)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:295)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
2021-06-23 18:24:43.269 1559-1680/? W/DocumentsContract: Failed to create document
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parent document isn't a directory
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:732)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:603)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2395)
        at android.provider.DocumentsContract.createDocument(DocumentsContract.java:1371)
        at com.android.documentsui.DocumentsAccess$RuntimeDocumentAccess.createDocument(DocumentsAccess.java:157)
        at com.android.documentsui.picker.CreatePickedDocumentTask.run(CreatePickedDocumentTask.java:79)
        at com.android.documentsui.picker.CreatePickedDocumentTask.run(CreatePickedDocumentTask.java:42)
        at com.android.documentsui.base.CheckedTask.doInBackground(CheckedTask.java:65)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.android.documentsui.ProviderExecutor.run(ProviderExecutor.java:104)
```

Comment: `trying to save/export a file on the user Documents shared folder` If you let the user use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT you get an uri for the newly created file. There is no folder involved in your code (which is ok) and you dont know in which folder the user created the file. The choosen folder is irrelevant.

Comment: I can select a folder from the UI, but I can't save the file. In fact, the writeFile is not even being run, the error is coming before it.

Comment: You are talking not understandable as ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT does not select a folder but creates a file in a folder where the user navigates to. Please tell better what happens. Is onActivityResult triggered,?

Comment: A better subject for your problem would be: ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT does not create a file but crashes.

Comment: `putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,......` You should start with removing that line as it can never work that way. Why didnt you tell that it did not work?

Comment: From my understanding, ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT is supposed to create a file after the user select which directory it should be saved and edit the name of the file or go with the default name set with EXTRA_TITLE. As I said, the error parent document is not a directory, then failed to create a document .... That's where I am stuck. 
Also, the onActivityResult is deprecated, I think the 3rd line with registerForActivityResult should be replacing what should be on onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the issue wasn't in my implementation, but my Android emulator. I tried to create a folder from the file manager (outside my application) and I was getting the same error. So, I tried testing my application on a physical device, it worked perfectly!

The issue with my emulator was that the SD card was corrupted (either it wasn't set up or something went wrong at some point without me realizing it). Resetting that fixed the issue